# Delete the page announcing a new part

Tags: parts, scrbook

Currently new parts are announced with a page containing the part number and name.

Is it possible to remove this page, while keeping the rest? (line in the table of contents, or the possible counters involving the part number etc)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Algebra}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Analysis}
\chapter{Chap 1}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The assumption is that `\part` should now point to the same page as the following `\chapter`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419404/4736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just update `\part` to perform ToC-related content insertion:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

% Update \part to not print anything within the document body, except elements within the ToC
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Algebra}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Analysis}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\cleardoublepage` is necessary to ensure you're on the same page as any subsequent `\chapter`.

Comment: With a KOMA-Script class you can use `\addparttocentry{\thepart}{#1}` or `\addxcontentsline{toc}{part}[\thepart]{#1}`.